# CloudFormation: AWS Glue Classifier Quote Symbol Sample values

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

Can anyone provide me the sample values to use for Quote Symbol in CloudFormation, when the crawler reads the data from source S3 buckets?

My source data has STX (Start of Text) characters to the column values and I'm unable to create data catalog with source schema. If I can create classifier through console, I am able to select /002 for STX characters. Unfortunately, I have read-only access on console.

```
CsvClassifier = list(
    Name = "string",
    Delimiter = "string",
    QuoteSymbol = "string", # <<< NOT SURE ON THE SAMPLE INPUT STRING HERE >>>
    ContainsHeader = "UNKNOWN"|"PRESENT"|"ABSENT",
    Header = list(
      "string"
    ),
    DisableValueTrimming = TRUE|FALSE,
    AllowSingleColumn = TRUE|FALSE
  )
```

Comment: have you tried  QuoteSymbol = " ' "   ?

Comment: It is a bug to use QuoteSymbol using CFTs